# MySQL Search across two tables

Tags: mysql

After a search, there's `$_GET['lang_know']` and `$_GET['lang_learn']` and each would output the 2 iso code of each language selected

How would I make it into one single search query? As in.. search `$_GET['lang_learn']` with `language_learn` and `$_GET['lang_know']` with `language_know` but one ONE query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by using a UNION.

```
SELECT a, b FROM language_learn WHERE c LIKE '%d%'
UNION
SELECT a, b FROM language_know WHERE c LIKE '%d%'
```